# Group functions in usercontrol

Tags: c#, function

I have some functions in my usercontrol, which are referring to one thing (ex. items: count and selectedIndex functions). How to group functions to be like:

```
usercontrol.group.function1
usercontrol.group.function2
```

instead of:

```
usercontrol.function1
usercontrol.function2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a static class called group within usercontrol. And add those functions to it

Answer (score 1):

Well, as C# is Object Oriented, I think the question you need to ask yourself is "Why are these things grouped together?" What similarities do all these functions have in common? Once you understand what they have in common, the best approach would be to create a class with the proper name, and add those methods as public methods.

```
public class UserControl { 
    public MyNewClass group;
}

public class MyNewClass {
    public void function1() {

    }

    public void function2() {

    }
}
```